# Virtual functions from base-class constructors

Tags: c#

I have summarized my problem in following code snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace St
{
    public  class Animal
    {
        public Animal()
        {
            Speak();
        }
      public virtual void Speak()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Animal speak");
      }
    }
    public  class Dog:Animal
    {
        private StringBuilder sb = null;

        public Dog()
        {
                sb=new StringBuilder();
        }
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bow...{0}",sb.Append("bow"));
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog d=new Dog();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile it it there is no error but when I ran it I am getting object reference error.

Comment: public override void Speak() in this method

Comment: Also setting a reference type field to null when you declare it is a waste of time and is a performance hit (even if it is pretty small)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling a virtual method in your constructor for Animal.

This is a dangerous practice - exactly for this reason.  The issue is that, when you construct a Dog, the "Animal" (base class) constructor is run **first**.  At this point, it calls `Speak()`.  However, Dog's `Speak` method relies on Dog's constructor having been run, so `sb` hasn't been initialized and is still `null`.

In general, virtual method calls in a constructor are a very bad idea - and a sign of a design flaw.  I'd recommend a different approach here.

---

My recommendation for reworking this would be to simply remove the `Speak()` from the constructor.  I would write this code as:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        // Don't do this in the constructor
        // Speak();
    }
    public virtual void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal speak");
    }
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    private StringBuilder sb = null;

    public Dog()
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    public override void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bow...{0}", sb.Append("bow"));
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.Speak();
    }
}
```

This makes more sense to me, from a logic standpoint as well.  This line:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```

Is responsible for a single action - constructing a new `Dog`.  I would not expect it, as a consumer of the class, to perform complex operations (ie: speaking) - merely to create and setup a Dog and its internal state correctly.

When I want it to speak, I specifically call:

```
d.Speak();
```

Comment: +1 for the design flaw of calling a virtual method in a constructor

Comment: @Reed:So, you mean we should  avoid calling virtual functions from base-class
constructors,

Comment: @geek: Exactly.  I believe this gets enforced by most source code analysis tools (such as the one in VS 2010, or FxCop, etc), as well, since it's a very dangerous practice.  It's just opens up a potential flaw, since you're using an object that, technically, hasn't been constructed yet (the subclass).

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because when you call the `Dog` constructor, the `Animal` constructor is called first, which then calls `Speak()`, but sb hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 2):

`Speak` is called from the base class constructor before `sb` has been intialized. What you need to do is initiaze the `StringBuilder` class just before it is needed.

### Update

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace St
{
    public  class Animal
    {
        public Animal()
        {
            Speak();
        }
      public virtual void Speak()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Animal speak");
      }
    }
    public  class Dog:Animal
    {
        private StringBuilder sb = null;

        public Dog()
        {  }
        public override void Speak()
        {
            if(sb==null) { sb = new StringBuilder(); }    // lazy init
            sb.Append("bow");
            Console.WriteLine("bow...{0}",sb.ToString());
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog d=new Dog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moving the `StringBuilder` instance to the base class is only applicable if it is actually desired to be part of the base implementation. In this case, it's specifically to support overriding the base implementation.

Comment: @Anthony: Then add a check in `Speak` override to intialize `sb` before it is used when `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The base Animal constructor will be called (and thus the virtual Dog::Speak) before the constructor for the Dog, meaning before you init the sb.

Depending on your exact design either:

1.Move the sb to your base class

2.Check for null sb in Dog::Speak (and init sb there)

3.Move the code out from the constructor into an Init (recommended)